# Reloading current route after delete request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing a CRUD application in React and I want to reload the current route which includes 'id' and 'name' of the object after the delete request using  'Axios'.
When I delete an object the page won't reload and the displayed data is the same as before deleting.
I tried history.push but it didn't work.
This is actually I want to do:
`history.push(`/addScenarioDetail/${scenarioId}/${name}`);`

```
   export default const AddScenarioDetail = ({ match }: Props) => {
   const {
       params: { id },
       params: { name }
   } = match;
   const classes = useStyles();
   const [scenarioId, setScenarioId] = useState('');
   const [layouts, setLayouts] = useState([]);
   const [displays, setDisplays] = useState([]);
   const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
   const [layoutId, setLayoutId] = useState('');
   const [displayId, setDisplayId] = useState('');
   const [layoutName, setLayoutName] = useState('');
   const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState('');
   const [detailsNames, setDetailsNames] = useState([]);
   let history = useHistory();
   const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
       let ignore = false;
       let num = parseInt(id, 10)
       setScenarioId(num);
       async function fetchData() {
           const layoutPromise = axios("http://localhost:8080/xiboscenario/layouts");
           const displayPromise = axios("http://localhost:8080/xiboscenario/displays");
           const detailPromise = axios(`http://localhost:8080/xiboscenario/${id}/detail`);
           const layoutResult = await layoutPromise;
           const displayResult = await displayPromise;
           const detailResult = await detailPromise;
           if (!ignore) {
               setLayouts(layoutResult.data);
               setDisplays(displayResult.data);
               setDetails(detailResult.data);
           }
       }
       fetchData();
       return () => { ignore = true; }
   }, [id]);

   async function handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
       await axios({
           method: 'post',
           url: `http://localhost:8080/xiboscenario/${scenarioId}/detail`,
           data: {
               scenario_id: scenarioId,
               display_id: displayId,
               layout_id: layoutId
           }
       });
       history.push(`/addScenarioDetail/${scenarioId}/${name}`);
   };

   async function removeDetail(id) {
       await axios.delete(`http://anpr.sportpaleisgroep.be:28080/xiboscenario/${scenarioId}/detail`, {
           data: {
               scenariodetail_id: id
           }
       })
       // history.push(`/addScenarioDetail/${scenarioId}/${name}`);
   }


   const handleClickOpen = () => {
       setOpen(true);
   };

   const handleClose = () => {
       setOpen(false);
   };

   return (
       <div className={classes.root}>
           <Paper className={classes.tablePaper}>
                       <DetailTable details={detailsNames} removeDetail={removeDetail} />
                   </Paper>
                   <Tooltip title="Add" aria-label="add">
                       <Fab className={classes.addButton}>
                           <AddIcon onClick={handleClickOpen} />
                       </Fab>
                   </Tooltip>
           <Dialog open={open} fullWidth={true} onClose={handleClose}
               maxWidth='md' aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
               <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Add Detail</DialogTitle>
               <div className={classes.addForm}>
                   <h2>{name}</h2>
                   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                       <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                           <Autocomplete
                               options={layouts.map(option => option.layout_name)}
                               id="controlled-demo"
                               value={layoutName}
                               onChange={handleLayoutChange}
                               renderInput={params => (
                                   <TextField {...params} label="Layout" fullWidth />
                               )}
                           />
                       </FormControl>
                       <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                           <Autocomplete
                               options={displays.map(option => option.display_name)}
                               id="controlled-demo"
                               value={displayName}
                               onChange={handleDisplayChange}
                               renderInput={params => (
                                   <TextField {...params} label="Display" fullWidth />
                               )}
                           />
                       </FormControl>
                       <br />
                       <Button variant="contained" type="submit" className={classes.saveFormButton}>Save</Button>
                   </form>
               </div>
               <br />
           </Dialog>
       </div>
     )
  }
```

And this my router:

```
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact={true} component={Home} />
          <Route path='/scenarioTable' component={ScenarioTable} />
          <Route path='/showScenarios' component={ShowScenarios} />
          <Route path='/update/:id' component={updateScenario} />
          <Route path='/addScenarioDetail/:id/:name' component={AddScenarioDetail} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do a `history.push` on the same page with `react-router` this will not do much, because React sees that it will be showing the same components so it will not unmount/remount them all, that's the idea behind React : only what needs to be changed will be changed.

Instead, what you want, after the delete, is simply update your state so that your UI updates.

Typically, do a `setState` instead of the `history.push`, that will update the state with all the items except the one that has been deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing same url in history with different variables(id,name) for dynamic url '/addScenarioDetail/:id/:name' wont reload the content. You need to check the updated route yourself in that component. Check below code

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if (this.props.match.params.id !== prevProps.match.params.id || this.props.match.params.name !== prevProps.match.params.name) {
        //do required action here like updating state, fetching new data from api
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe a simple `window.location.reload()` would be enough to reload the page.

And if you need it to reload at a different URL just `window.location = "OTHER_URL"`

Also, from your code it seems you are using alot of `useState()`, if your state is "complex" might I suggest having a look at `useReducer()`?

Link to docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: This will reload all the page, kind of loosing the idea of a single page application, tough ...

Comment: Because the state used in the table is created in another `useEffect()` based on an API I can't use `useState()` directly delete handler.

This is how I create that state:

Comment: `useEffect((prevProps) => {
async function fetchData() {const detailsName = []; let layout_name = '';
 let display_name = '';
 let detail_id = '';
  for (let detail of details) {
  detail_id = detail.detail_id
 for (let display of displays) {
 if (detail.display_id === display.display_id) {
display_name = display.display_name
 }
}
for (let layout of layouts) {
if (detail.layout_id === layout.layout_id) {
layout_name = layout.layout_name
 }
}detailsName.push({ display_name, layout_name, detail_id })
display_name = ''; layout_name = ''; }
setDetailsNames(detailsName);`